# Java Get MulticastSocket.receive to Throw ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, multicastsocket

I have some code that reads data from a multicast socket until a user-defined end time.  I would also like to stop reading data if the thread is interrupted via a call to `Thread.interrupt` (or by any other user-initiated action you can come up with).  I can't figure out how to get notification when the thread is interrupted.  The existing code is as follows:

```
// These are the constants I am given
final int         mcastPort = ...;
final InetAddress mcastIP   = ...;
final InetAddress ifaceIP   = ...; // Null indicates all interfaces should be used
final Instant     endTime   = ...; // Time at which to stop processing

// Initialize a datagram
final byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

// Process incoming datagram packets
try (final MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port)) {
    socket.joinGroup(mcastIP);
    if (ifaceIP != null)
        socket.setInterface(ifaceIP);

    do {
        final Duration soTimeout = Duration.between(Instant.now(), endTime);
        socket.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
        socket.receive(packet);

        // Process packet
        ...
    } while (true);
} catch (final SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // Normal condition... the recording time has ended
} catch (final ClosedByInterruptException e) {
    // Uh-oh... this never happens
} ...
```

I saw that there was a `DatagramSocket.getChannel` method that returns a `DatagramChannel`, so I naturally assumed that type was used to read/write to the underlying socket.  That assumption was incorrect, which means that `MulticastSocket` doesn't implement `InterruptibleChannel`.  Because of this, `MulticastSocket.receive` never throws a `ClosedByInterruptException`.

I have searched online for examples, but can't figure out how to modify the above code to use a `DatagramChannel` instead of a `MulticastSocket`.  The problems I need help with are:

1. How do I set the SO_TIMEOUT parameter on a DatagramChannel?
2. How do I convert an `InetAddress` into a `NetworkInterface` object?

The following is my best guess on how to convert my implementation from `MulticastSocket` to `DatagramChannel` to meet my requirements:

```
// Initialize a buffer
final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);

try (final DatagramChannel mcastChannel = DatagramChannel.open()) {
    mcastChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
    mcastChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    mcastChannel.join(mcastIP);
    if (ifaceIP != null)
        // HELP: this option requires an InterfaceAddress object,
        //       but I only have access to an InetAddress object
        mcastChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ifaceIP);

    do {
        final Duration soTimeout = Duration.between(Instant.now(), endTime);
        // HELP: SO_TIMEOUT is not a member of StandardSocketOptions
        mcastChannel.setOption(SO_TIMEOUT, ???);
        mcastChannel.receive(buffer);

        // Process packet
        ...
    } while (true);
} ...
```

Will this approach even work?  `DatagramChannel.receive` doesn't list `SocketTimeoutException` as one of the exceptions it is able to throw.  If this will work, then please let me know how I need to change the second implementation to be equivalent to the first, but with the ability to throw a `ClosedByInterruptException` when a client calls `Thread.interrupt`.  If not, then does anyone have any other ideas as to how I can meet the requirement of stopping datagram reception at a pre-defined time, while also providing a way to stop execution via user interaction?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set the SO_TIMEOUT parameter on a DatagramChannel?

By calling `channel.socket().setSoTimeout()`.

> How do I convert an `InetAddress` into a `NetworkInterface` object?

You enumerate the network interfaces until you find one with the required address.

> `DatagramChannel.receive()` doesn't list `SocketTimeoutException`

It doesn't have to. It lists `IOException`, and `SocketTimeoutException` extends `IOException`.

Your second piece of code should call `bind()`, not `connect()`, and it should set the intterface before calling `join()`, not after. Apart from that, it should work as expected once you fix the network interface issue, and it will throw `ClosedByInterruptException` if interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The final, working code is:

```
// Create a datagram packet used to read multicast data from the socket
final byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

// Process incoming datagram packets
try (final DatagramChannel mcastChannel =
        DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)) {

    // Set the appropriate parameters on the socket
    mcastChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
    mcastChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    if (ifaceIP == null) {
        // Call join on each NetworkInterface that supports IPv4 multicast
    } else {
        mcastChannel.join(mcastIP, NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ifaceIP));
    }

    final DatagramSocket socket = mcastChannel.socket();

    do {
        final Duration timeToEnd = Duration.between(Instant.now(), endTime);
        if (timeToEnd.compareTo(Duration.ZERO) < 0) break;

        socket.setSoTimeout((int)timeToEnd.toMillis());
        socket.receive(packet);

        // Process packet
        ...
    } while (true);
} catch (final SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // The end time has passed
} catch (final ClosedByInterruptException e) {
    // The user initiated the closure
} ...
```

Things to note:

1. The call to `socket.receive`.  If this is changed to `mcastChannel.receive`, you will never get a `SocketTimeoutException`.
2. The call to `bind` occurs prior to the call(s) to `join`.  You can call `join` as many times as you want, on as many distinct network interfaces.